# Swift 1.2: 'self' used before super.init call

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
class SomeViewController : UIViewController {

 let deferred : ()->()

 required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    deferred = {
        self.doSomething()
    }

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }

 func doSomething() {
    // Does things....
 }

}
```

In Swift 1.2 this fails to compile with the error:

'self' used before super.init call

In pre-1.2 days, we can address this in a number of ways such as implicitly unwrapped conditionals. That approach won't work any longer.

I've seen other answers reference 2-stage initialization or the lazy decorator, but both sacrifice immutability of the property. Surely this must be solvable in Swift 1.2, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply move the call to `super` *before* you use `self`?  It's exactly what the error is telling you, and I see no reason looking at the code why this shouldn't be okay, and you've explained no reason.

Comment: @nhgrif: But you cannot call `super.init()` before `self` (including the `deferred` property) has been completely initialized.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, I see.  Makes sense now.  Except... if this worked, wouldn't it create a retain cycle on `self`?

Comment: @nhgrif: Yes, but that is a different problem (and can be solved with capturing `self` weakly).

Comment: @MattD Since you are not actually sending a message to `self` but merely referring to it in the course of constructing your anonymous function, this would make a pretty good use case to file a bug report. Apple closed some loopholes with regard to initialization in Swift 1.2 and they may have closed the door a little more tightly than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an interim workaround:

```
private(set) var deferred : ()->() = { }

required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.deferred = {
        self.doSomething()
    }

}
```

My thinking is, okay, we did "sacrifice immutability of the property", but from a public perspective the property remains immutable because the setter is private.

Comment: I'll file this. Thanks.